# Perfect past vs past simple

Tags: past-tense

Somebody I am currently tutoring has the following question in a work book:

> I was taught that Shakespeare (    ?         ) in 1616
>
> a) had died
> b) died
> c) has died
> d) dies

The correct answer marked in the book is (b) "died". However, I am unsure of the reasoning.
As far as I can tell "had died" and "died" (a and b) should both be grammatically correct and work in this context. But I was wondering how to explain why the book chose this over the other.

Comment: It wouldn't be particularly common, but it's perfectly okay to "backshift" to ***had died*** in your exact context (because you've already invoked the past with ***I was taught***). Without that prior past tense context, as in - *I **know** that Shakespeare **had died** in 1616*, it would ***not*** be acceptable to use the Past Perfect form. Basically, your textbook isn't very good.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you that both (a) and (b) are possible answers.

As a simple statement of fact, we would use (b). However, this sentence is a bit more complex. You could say "I always thought that Shakespeare *had died* in 1615, but my teacher says it was 1616."